# Node+express+Angular- calling route results in infinite loop call of controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am using node js with express. Angular js files are loaded through index.html

app.js code

```
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.engine('html', engines.nunjucks);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '\\views');

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));


app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
 });

app.listen(3006, function() {
  console.log("listening");
 }); //the port you want to use
```

index.html code

```
<head>
    <base href="/" />
     <!-- META -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">      
</head>
<body ng-app="movies-app">
     <div ng-view><!--view will be injected here --></div>

    <script src="/js/lib/angular.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
    <script src="/js/lib/angular-sanitize.js"></script><!-- load angular sanitize -->
    <script src="/js/lib/angular-route.js"></script><!-- load angular route -->
    <script src="/js/movieApp.js"></script><!-- load controller -->
    <script src="/js/controllers/mainController.js"></script><!-- load controller -->
</body>
```

movieApp.js

```
 var movieApp = angular.module('movies-app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize','mainController']);

 movieApp. config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when("/movie", {
            templateUrl : '/views/movie.html',
            controller : 'movieController'
    }) .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

 }]);
```

mainController.js code

```
 var mainController = angular.module('mainController', []);

     mainController.controller('movieController', ['$scope','$http',    function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("contro");
    $scope.test = "Yeppeee";
}]);
```

When i am hitting http://localhost:3006 a blank page appears, as expected. Edit URL to http://localhost:3006/movie, console will show infinite loop of text "contro".

Please help.

Comment: Could you also post the content of `/views/movie.html`?

Comment: For testing i've put dummy content: - " <h2>Movies List</h2>{{test}}"

Answer (score 0):

Seems issue with the server code, when you opened localhost:3006/movie it sends html, from a browser done some request and server respond by sending same html again and app starting work again, so there is loop, try to comment this part

```
 app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
   // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
   res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
 });
```

And serve index.html as static, also check from developers tools are there requests to the server.